# Sects of Hinduism

Tags: krishna, dharma, sects, brahmins

One of my friend is a Vaishnavite Brahmin....but he says, has increased devotion to Lord Shiva and is much affected by Shaivism. Since he is the eldest son in home, he became responsible for pujas, havans, etc which are laid on him as responsibility. As he has became a devotee of Lord Shiva, he tried to replace the family devotee as Lord Krishna to Lord Shiva, which was opposed by his family and his caste/sub-caste society. He asked for help. He want to convert to Shaivism officially/religiously, so that his people accept this. He said he doesn't want to fight with society, but want to live with peace. What he must do? He needs help????

Comment: This question will give opinion based answers. So, please change your question to " Is there any procedure to change Kula Deva or something else?" before someone close it. Coming to your friend, my Ista Deva is Shiva and i worship Him on Mondays while we too worship our Kula Devata Ankamma. **By worshiping different aspects of Brahman, we know more about Brahman and this is beauty of our Sanatana Dharma. Try to convince your friend saying that worshiping or knowing  both will help him in understanding Brahman**. Most of people now-a-days, believe both are same and doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 7):

Being a devotee of Lord Shiva does not give him rights to alter the Kula Devata of his family.So that is not right.

Moreover, if one is a "true" devotee of any God,then he sees all Gods as same and  one with his Ista Devata.

He can worship Lord Shiva at the beginning of his daily religous duties before starting the pujas and havans that he is supposed to do for his family or community.

I can  also not understand how by worshipping Lord Krishna will lessen the devotion that he has for Lord Shiva?

Lord Krishna Himself was a earnest devotee of Lord Shiva in his lifetime.

So i don't see why and how this is such a big problem for your friend.

Comment: But there's much difference. If there is freedom of religion then why not also freedom of religious sect? If a man is Moslem, he can convert to Christianity or Hinduism etc., but why can't he convert to other sect. If my friend wants to spread Shaivism among his people, why not, because they already are Hindus, why can't he create a new branch among his people/society/caste which believes in Shaivism rather than Vaishnavism. Many Hindus of traditional sects converted to Arya Samaj Hinduism, during British, but they didn't converted to other religion, they accepted a new form/sect of Hinduism.

Comment: It is ideally wrong to force other people to believe what you believe in by making it something mandatory.Istadevata varies from person to person and can be judged from one's horoscope too.Every person is free to choose his or her own ista devata.Just because i love lord shiva does not mean i'll forcefully convert all other krishna vakts or ganapaty vakts to shaivism.That is wrong from my point of view.

Comment: I don't mean forcefully, bro!

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the two concepts of ishtadetaa and kula devtaa.

- he can change his ishtdevtaa(due to "his" own freedom of religious sect), it is his individual choice.
- but he can not change his kuldevtaa , just due to his own freedom of religious sect. For that all the persons in his kula/extended kula have to agree(democratically agree), as they all have their own freedom of religious sect. Freedom of choosing of choosing "kuladevtaa" is made of sum of agreement of every individual in kula right to choose kuladevtaa. And hence kuladevtaa does not change so often.

Why he needs to force his choice of ishtdevtaa as kuldevtaa on everyone?
So his right to worship does "not" mean "only my right of worship". Right of worship means "right of worship by each individual(sihtdevtaa) and also democratic right of worship by each social group(say,kula)".

And **hence he can personally worship the kuldevtaa(due to overall democratic majoritarian right of kula) "and" additionally he can also worship ishtdevtaa(due to his democratic right to worship). And everybody else can worship their own ishtdevtaa and the kuldevtaa. Thats the meaning of democratic right of worship.**